# ¿Como Hacer un OR con RouteIs de Laravel?

Tags: laravel, blade, laravel-8

Tengo el siguiente codigo en blade de laravel y quisiera saber como se hacer un OR en `{{request()->routeIs()}}`, es decir ***"si es esta ruta cargo" o "si es esta ruta logeo"***

```
<li class="nav-item btn-group dropright py-2">
    <a class="nav-link {{request()->routeIs('admin.cargo')?'font-weight-bold active':'text-dark'}} dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Más </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu bg-light">                                    
      <a href="{{route('admin.cargo')}}" class="dropdown-item text-dark">Cargos</a>
      <a href="{{route('admin.logeo')}}" class="dropdown-item text-dark">Logeos</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

uso routeIs para marcarme los elementos de una barra de navegación como activos que me funciona bien con los otros elementos, pero en esta parte como esta dentro de un dropdown con 2 opciones necesito usarlo de esa manera, es en la linea 2 del codigo que estoy mostrando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la solución que se encontro es la siguiente:

```
<li class="nav-item btn-group dropright py-2">
    <a class="nav-link {{(request()->routeIs('admin.cargo')||request()->routeIs('admin.logeo'))?'font-weight-bold active':'text-dark'}} dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Más </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu bg-light">                                    
      <a href="{{route('admin.cargo')}}" class="dropdown-item text-dark">Cargos</a>
      <a href="{{route('admin.logeo')}}" class="dropdown-item text-dark">Logeos</a>
    </div>
</li>
```